# How do I determine why glfwCreateWindow returned null

Tags: linux, opengl, glfw

When I call `glfwCreateWindow` on Linux, it returns `NULL`. The same code works on Windows, and I have appropriate graphics drivers installed. How do I determine why it returns null?

EDIT: Turns out it returned null because the version of OpenGL I asked for is apparently not available on my netbook. This solves my problem, but doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: You get anything via [`glfwSetErrorCallback()`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__error.html#gaa5d796c3cf7c1a7f02f845486333fb5f)?

Comment: @genpfault Doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same problem in Mac.
I annotated the following parts, the problem fixed!

```js
//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE);
//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you develop with Mac OS. you need code like:

```
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
#ifdef __APPLE__
// compat mac os
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
```